# PyTorch: Dynamic Programming as Tensor Operation

Tags: python, pytorch, dynamic-programming, tensor

Is it possible to get the following loop with a Tensor operation?

```py
a = torch.Tensor([1, 0, 0, 0])
b = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])

for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
    a[i] = b[i] + a[i-1]

print(a) # [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

The operation depends on the previous values in `a` and the values that are computed on the way (in a dynamic programming fashion).

Is it possible to get this type of sequential computation with a tensor operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [cumulative sum](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cumsum.html):

```py
b.cumsum(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Classic case of not knowing the correct term for what I was trying to do.