# PyTorch Tensor Operation for adding the maximum of the previous row to the next

Tags: python, pytorch, dynamic-programming, tensor

Follow-Up question to [PyTorch: Dynamic Programming as Tensor Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919743/pytorch-dynamic-programming-as-tensor-operation).

Could the following be written as a tensor operation instead of a loop?

```py
a = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [5, 6, 7, 8],
                  [9, 10, 11, 12]])

print(a.shape) 
# (3, 4)

for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
    a[i] = a[i-1].max(dim=0)[0] + a[i]

print(a)
# tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
#         [21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Basically adding the maximum of the previous row to all elements of the next.

The interesting part is that you can't compute the maximum for each row beforehand and then add that to the respective row, because adding the first maximum influences what the maximum of the next row is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you're trying to do this, but yes, this is possible. It's basically the same as your last question:

```
max_vals, _ = a.max(axis=1, keepdim=True)
additions = max_vals.cumsum(0)[:-1]
a[1:, :] += additions
```

This is because the marginal addition from one row to the next is equivalent to the maximum, so you can take the maximums first, then cumulatively sum them and add them to the original tensor.

Comment: Nice thank you! Yeah sorry for being slow about generalizing the cumsum concept and I didn't think of the trick with doing the cumsum on the maximums! I am implementing a Viterbi Decode where stuff like that is necessary.

Comment: Ah cool! Sorry, I didn’t mean my comment to come off as snarky, I was genuinely curious what you were doing. Thanks for the challenging question, and best of luck on your decoder!

Comment: No problem :) I mean you can always use loops but nothing is more beautiful than some concise tensor operations :D

Comment: Oh absolutely agreed - and so, so much faster